# I have a subset matrix extracted from a data frame, how can I get the corresponding row names?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, subset

```
A=data.frame(Lat=(1:5),long=(6:10))
rownames(A)<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
B=matrix(c(2,7,4,9),nrow=2,ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
```

How can I get the corresponding row names "b" and "d" for matrix B from data frame A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `row.match` in the package `prodlim`, which is very easy to use. It returns a vector with the row numbers of (first) matches and `NA` otherwise. You can use that vector (`m` in this example) to identify the rownames of `A` for which a match was found in `B`.

```
library(prodlim)
m <- row.match(A, B)
rownames(A)[!is.na(m)]
#[1] "b" "d"
```

Comment: thank you milan for you prompt reply! I think your way is fast simple and effective!

Comment: @CHUNMING SHI; thanks for the comments and you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

If we are comparing elementwise, then convert 'A' to `matrix`, check whether the elements are `%in%` B, convert the logical vector to `matrix`, get the row index with `which/arr.ind=TRUE` and based on that find the row names.

```
row.names(A)[unique(which(`dim<-`(as.matrix(A) %in% B, dim(A)), arr.ind=TRUE)[,1])]
#[1] "b" "d"
```

---

Or if we are comparing corresponding columns in 'A' and 'B', we can do with `mapply`, get the `rowSums`,  check whether it is 2 and find the row names based on that index.

```
row.names(A)[rowSums(mapply(function(x,y) x %in% y, A, as.data.frame(B)))==2]
```

Or we can `paste` the columns together and compare

```
row.names(A)[do.call(paste, A) %in% paste(B[,1], B[,2])]
#[1] "b" "d"
```

NOTE: All these methods are based on `base R`

Comment: thank you akrun! thank you for so many solutions!  you code really works in my case !

Answer (score 0):

Another method you can try in base R

```
row.names(A)[A[,1] %in% B[,1] & A[,2] %in% B[,2]]
[1] "b" "d"
```